# return value from jquery modal dialog hat links to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

am creating a jquery modal dialog and linking it to a form in another page like this:

```
var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
.html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
.dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   height: 400,
   width: 300,
   title: "Multiple HAWBs",
   buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {}
});
$dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

on the linked page I have a  element and I am trying to read the selected values from the dialog to my parent page, how canI do this?

Answer (score 0):

If iframe's source is different domain, you can't do that. In other case you can access its content by adding an id to that element

```
<iframe id="myiframe" style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>'
```

and then simply

```
document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.document
```

Answer (score 0):

see if this is something you need:[HERE](http://main.xfiddle.com/60abc423/demo1.php)

**demo.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".click").on('click',function(){
    myDialog();
});
});
function myDialog(){
var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
.html('<iframe style="border: 0px;" id="frame" src="view1.php" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 400,
    width: 300,
    title: "Multiple HAWBs",
    buttons: {
         "Save": function() {
             var data="";
            var childrens= $($(document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document)[0].activeElement).children();//get allthe fields of dialog
         childrens.each(function(index){
     if(childrens[index].id == 'addme1'){
        data=data+childrens[index].value;//this is just to show you the reading of content of dialog.
        }

         })
             $( this ).empty();
            $("#parent").html(data);

             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         },
         "Cancel": function() {
             $( this ).dialog( "close" );
         }
     },
     close: function() {

     }
});
$dialog.dialog('open');

}
</script>

<div>
<div id="parent">i'll be changed using dialog data</div>
<button class="click">Open Dialog</button>
```

**view1.php**

```
<input type="text" id="addme">
<input type="text" id="addme1">
```

Comment: hello, instead of getting all the elements of the dialog, how can i select a specific element?

Comment: @ThairAbdalla try to get it by it,s id. i'll update the answer.

Comment: I do not have background in php but is this statement legit in javascript:
if(childrens[index].id == 'addme1'){
        data=data+childrens[index].value;//this is just to show you the reading of content of dialog.
        }

Comment: this entire code is `javascript and jquery`, only file extension is `.php`, you can use `.html ` also.

Comment: what is not working explain properly.it should take the value of second field.

Comment: I just saw the edit, one last problem, I have a function that I used to pass the value for it like this:   thisPage.navigate.ExportFormatted($("#lstExportTemplates").val());

how can I pass the data instead of  $("#parent").html(data);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93686/discussion-between-suchit-and-thair-abdalla).

Comment: try using:thisPage.navigate.ExportFormatted(data); or simply ExportFormatted(data); based on your structure.

Comment: i guess you should edit your question or ask a new one.